# Returning most recent row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
OrderID int,
Person varchar(10),
LastModified Date
);


INSERT INTO Test (OrderID, Person, LastModified)
VALUES (1,  'Sam', '2018-05-15'),
(1,  'Tim','2018-05-14'),
(1,  'Kim','2018-05-05'),
(1,  'Dave','2018-05-13'),
(1,  'James','2018-05-11'),
(1,  'Fred','2018-05-05');
```

select * result:

```
| OrderID | Person | LastModified |
|---------|--------|--------------|
|       1 |    Sam |   2018-05-15 |
|       1 |    Tim |   2018-05-14 |
|       1 |    Kim |   2018-05-05 |
|       1 |   Dave |   2018-05-13 |
|       1 |  James |   2018-05-11 |
|       1 |   Fred |   2018-05-05 |
```

I am looking to return the most recent modified row which is the first row with 'Sam'.

Now i now i can use max to return the most recent date but how can i aggregate the person column to return sam?

Looking for a result set like

```
| OrderID | Person | LastModified |
|---------|--------|--------------|
|       1 |    Sam |   2018-05-15 |
```

I ran this:

```
SELECT 
OrderID,
max(Person) AS [Person],
max(LastModified) AS [LastModified]
FROM Test
GROUP BY 
OrderID
```

but this returns:

```
| OrderID | Person | LastModified |
|---------|--------|--------------|
|       1 |    Tim |   2018-05-15 |
```

Can someone advice me further please? thanks

*** UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO Test (OrderID, Person, LastModified)
VALUES (1,  'Sam', '2018-05-15'),
(1,  'Tim','2018-05-14'),
(1,  'Kim','2018-05-05'),
(1,  'Dave','2018-05-13'),
(1,  'James','2018-05-11'),
(1,  'Fred','2018-05-05'),
(2,  'Dave','2018-05-13'),
(2,  'James','2018-05-11'),
(2,  'Fred','2018-05-05');
```

So i would be looking for this result to be:

```
| OrderID | Person | LastModified |
|---------|--------|--------------|
|       1 |    Sam |   2018-05-15 |
|       2 |   Dave |   2018-05-13 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want just one record (the latest modified one) per `OrderID` then this would do it:

```
SELECT
      t2.OrderID
    , t2.Person
    , t2.LastModified

FROM (
    SELECT
          MAX( LastModified ) AS LastModified
        , OrderID

    FROM 
        Test

    GROUP BY
        OrderID
) t

INNER JOIN Test t2
    ON t2.LastModified = t.LastModified
    AND t2.OrderID = t.OrderID
```

Comment: thanks very much, is there a way i can do this if there is more than one orderID e.g. multiple people and lastmodified for multiple orderID's?

Comment: Could you update your question with more sample data to cover these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on your comment (*"thanks very much, is there a way i can do this if there is more than one orderID e.g. multiple people and lastmodified for multiple orderID's?"*), in xcvd's answer, I assume what you therefore want is this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT OrderId,
           Person,
           LastModifed,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY LastModified DESC) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT OrderID,
       Person,
       LastModified
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.*
FROM Test t
ORDER BY LastModified DESC;
```

If you want this for each `orderid`, then this is a handy method in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
FROM Test t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY LastModified DESC);
```

Comment: back to basics approach  ;). +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

"xcvd's" answer is perfect for this, I would just like to add another solution that can be used here for the sake of showing you a method that can be used in more complex situations than this. This solution uses a nested query (sub-query) to find the MAX(LastModified) regardless of any other field and it will use the result in the original query's WHERE clause to find any results that meet the new criteria. Cheers.

```
SELECT OrderID
    , Person
    , LastModified
FROM Test
WHERE LastModified IN (SELECT MAX(LastModified)
                       FROM Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other method :

```
select t.*
from Test t
where LastModified = (select max(t1.LastModified) from Test t1 where t1.OrderID = t.OrderID);
```